# If $Y$ is simply connected, then it doesn't admit covering maps that aren't homeomorphisms

Tags: algebraic-topology, connectedness, covering-spaces

Let be $Y$ a simply connected space. Show that $Y$ doesn't admit covering maps that aren't homeomorphisms, ie, every cover space of $Y$ is trivial ($I\times Y$, with $I$ a discrete space).

So, I know that if $f:X\to Y$ is a cover map and $Y$ is a connected space, then the cardinal of $p^{-1}(y)$, for each $y\in Y$, is constant, and that a homeomorphism between $X$ and $Y$ is a cover maps such that $\# p^{-1}(y)=1$, for every $y\in Y.$

Any idea?

Comment: Well, what do you know about coverings? Unless you give us some information about what you know and what you can use to prove this, we cannot help much. (Indeed, this is trivial for some definitions of simply connected!)

Comment: (Notice that the only way that the projection $I\times Y\to Y$ is a homeo is that $I$ have exactly one point...)

Comment: So, I know that if $f:X\to Y$ is a cover map and $Y$ is a connected space, then the cardinal of $p^{-1}(y)$, for each $y\in Y$, is constant, and that a homeomorphism between $X$ and $Y$ is a cover maps such that $\# p^{-1}(y)=1$, for every $y\in Y.$

Comment: You also need path-connectedness of $X$. Otherwise, one could cover $Y$ by a topological sum of some copies of $Y$. But maybe that's part of your definition of a covering space.

Answer (score 2):

If $Y$ is simply connected then it admits universal covering space trivially $(Y,id)$. You should know that if a space $Y$ has universal cover then this is a covering space of all covering spaces of $Y$. Thus, if $(X,p)$ is a covering space of $Y$ then there exits a homomorphism  $\psi$ (which is also a cover map) between $X$ and $Y$ such that $p \circ \psi=id$ (imagine the diagram). By the definition of cover map, $\psi$ and $p$ are continuous and surjective; with the above condition you observe that $p$ is also injective. Moreover $p$ is a cover map then it is a local homeomorphism which implies it is an open map.

Recap: we have found that $p$ is an open continuos bijective map, hence it is a homeomorphism.

Comment: If you use the universal property of the universal cover then it is trivial. If you want to complete the proof initiated by OP, and it was not clear how to conclude that the fibers are singletons, you just need to apply monodromy. Then an injective covering map is an isomorphism as you know.